# Update JFrame size automatically after addition of new components

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a JFrame with a JPanel inside (default stuff when using Window Builder Pro). In my code I am adding a new JPanel, but the outer JFrame fails to re-size to accomodate for the new components. So I have to drag manually.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

How can I make it so that no matter what I put in there, the JFrame automatically updates its size to accommodate for the new Swing components?

Comment: Sorry I meant for the Visible JFrame, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After adding the new component, try calling

```
frame.pack()
```

on the enclosing frame.  The pack method will set the size of the frame based on the size of its underlying components.  This is actually a method of the Window class, documentation available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29)

If you don't have a reference to the Window/Frame handy, an easy method is to call
[SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor%28java.awt.Component%29)() on the panel ***after*** it has been added.

Comment: Where I am adding the new Panels, I do not have access to the original JFrame object. Is there another way to get at it? or must I pass it as a parameter?

Comment: See above edit with an example of how to get a reference if you don't have one.

Answer (score 2):

How to achieve this in WindowsBuilder I can't say, but when running, simply call `pack` on the frame

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to reshape the enclosing native window, frame, or dialog to fit its contents is `pack`.  See [the example here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html).  If you need access to e.g. a frame from a lightweight child, you can get it with

```
JFrame topFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
```